# Questions about file objects : removing, closing etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, scope

1. Does `os.remove(<file_object>.name)` automatically close `<file_object>` ? Should I do a `<file_object>.close()` beforehand ?
2. What happens to all attributes of `<file_object>` after `<file_object>.close()` or equivalent closure, for example, is `<file_object>.close(); print(<file_object>.name)` reliably valid, and how/why.

Comment: `os.remove()` takes a path, not a file object.

Comment: @KlausD. my bad, corrected the typo

Comment: The behavior here is platform dependent.

Comment: Does https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove not cover it? It seems pretty clear in how it behaves both on Windows and on Unix.

Comment: I don't understand your question 2)... *nothing* happens to the attributes of the file-object after you `.close` it.... well, `.closed` changes from `False` to `True`...

Comment: Mike & juanpa : so is it right to interpret that : a) it is best to `close()` before `os.remove()` and b) attributes still exist after closing ..?

Comment: Why do you think closing the file object will make the attributes disappear?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was under the presumption that the memory associated with the variable would be cleaned up considering closing the file is a strong indication that one is done with it ?

Comment: @user426 I think you fundamentally misunderstand how Python works. Python is an object-oriented, high level, memory managed language. Objects will continue to exist as long as they are referenced. Variables aren't "associated" with memory, like say, C. Variables are just names that refer to objects, not memory. You have an object, a file object. You use a method on that object, `.close()`. That object is still referenced, and will continue to exist as long as it is referenced somewhere. After that, it is free for garbage collection.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is accurate, I am new to Python, though not very new. I'm more experienced in lower level programming, specifically C-style work. Still yet to wrap my head around variables and gc i guess.

Comment: @user426 again, **not at all like C**. Python provides *no way to handle the memory of an object*. In CPython, underneath the hood, all objects exist on a privately managed heap. Variables are just *names in namespaces that refer to objects*.  That is why I can do something like, `x = {"x":1}; x = 32` even though those are two completely different types.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand now , got it. Thank You.

Comment: Yeah, it's best to just leave behind most of the mental model of what's going on with C behind and learn Python on its own terms. Read the following primer, https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html it is very helpful for bootstrapping a solid mental model of Python's semantics.